# How to make regexp for multiple condition?

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

I have regexp code like below (I'm using VerbalExpression dart plugin ), My purpose is to check that a string starts with "36", followed by "01", "02", or "03". After that can be anything as long as the whole string is 16 characters long.

```
  var regex = VerbalExpression()
  ..startOfLine()
  ..then("36")
  ..then("01")
  ..or("02")
  ..anythingBut(" ")
  ..endOfLine();
String nik1 = "3601999999999999";
String nik2 = "3602999999999999";
String nik3 = "3603999999999999";

print('result : ${regex.hasMatch(nik1)}');
print('Hasil : ${regex.hasMatch(nik2)}');
print('Hasil : ${regex.hasMatch(nik3)}');
```

my code only true for nik1 and nik2, however i want true for nik3, I noticed that i can't put or() after or() for multiple check, it just give me all false result,  how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `VerbalExpression`, but a `RegExp` that does this is straightforward enough.

```
const pattern = r'^36(01|02|03)\S{12}$';

void main() {
  final regex = RegExp(pattern);
  print(regex.hasMatch('3601999999999999'));    // true
  print(regex.hasMatch('3602999999999999'));    // true
  print(regex.hasMatch('3603999999999999'));    // true
  print(regex.hasMatch('360199999999999'));     // false
  print(regex.hasMatch('3600999999999999'));    // false
  print(regex.hasMatch('36019999999999999'));   // false
}
```

Pattern explanation:

- The `r` prefix means dart will interpret it as a raw string ("$" and "\" are not treated as special).
- The `^` and `$` represent the beginning and end of the string, so it will only match the whole string and cannot find matches from just part of the string.
- `(01|02|03)` "01" or "02" or "03". `|` means OR. Wrapping it in parentheses lets it know where to stop the OR.
- `\S` matches any non-whitespace character.
- `{12}` means the previous thing must be repeated 12 times, so `\S{12}` means any 12 non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob for your detailed answer and corrected post, it looks like I don't need verbal expression :)